# Is it possible to have if/case in select

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to write a sql query that returns a set of columns based on a condition? below is a sample query:

```
Select 
    id
    ,name
    ,col3

From 
Table A
,left outer join (If (select col6 from table D =='A')
 {
     Select col3,col4,col5 as id
      From Table A
      ,left join table C
      ,left join
  }
 Else If (select col6 from table D =='D')
 {
   Select Col1, Col3 as id
    From Table A
  } ) as temp_tab on temp_tab.id = table A.id

,left outer join Table R on table R.name = table A.name

where id = 129
```

Comment: The syntax/approach you are using isn't possible, but if you add sample data to your question, someone may be able to give you a workaround.

Comment: Thanks guys!! I just wanted to check if this was even possible to write in sql,so didnt want to complicate with more schema or data. I'll try it first and repost what I got with details.

Comment: Is possible but not like you try here. The problem is in your example your final query only end with `id, name, col3` so dont make sense you bring `col1, col4, col5` from the other subquery. There for we dont know where the col3 you want came from.  If you include some data and a desire output we can help you to build the query

Comment: You can do this with dynamic SQL or ref cursors, which means **a procedural approach**. So you need to be clear about what it is you are trying to do and what benefits you hope to gain. This particularly affects how your code is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with dynamic SQL or ref cursors, which means a procedural approach. So you need to be clear about what it is you are trying to do and what benefits you hope to gain. This particularly affects how your code is called.

If you need a pure SQL approach you can try something like this. The projection of the inline view (`temp_tab`) is static but its actual values vary according to the content of `d.col6`.

```
select 
    x.id
    ,x.name
    ,temp_tab.col3
    ,temp_tab.col4
    ,temp_tab.id
from x
left outer join 
 (
     select case 
                when d.col6 = 'A' then a.col3 
                when d.col6 = 'D' then a.col1
                else null 
            end as col3
            ,case 
                when d.col6 = 'A' then c.col4
                else null
             end as col4
            ,case 
                when d.col6 = 'A' then a.col5 
                when d.col6 = 'D' then a.col3
                else null
             end as id
      from d
           cross join a
           left outer join c on a.whatever = c.whatever
      where (d.col6 = 'D' or c.whatever is not null)      
 ) as temp_tab on temp_tab.id = x.id
where x.id = 129
```

Depending on your precise requirements this may suffice for you, but obviously it is quite a clunky solution. Dynamically changing the tables in the FROM clause or the conditions in WHERE clause is tricky to impossible: if you need to do that you're looking at using dynamic SQL.